# How can I automate the process of logging intro a website and navigating to desired pages to retrieve data?

Tags: python

I'm working in a Windows system. I need to automate the following manual process:

1. Open a customer Excel file and retrieve (copy) a customer record number. This file includes a list of, say, 50 customer records.
2. Log into a website with my user ID and password.
3. Paste the customer record into the website customer search box, and click the Retrieve button to retrieve customer record info.
4. Navigate to several pages (for that specific customer) to copy data from several desired fields.
5. Paste this data back into the customer Results columns of the same customer Excel file for that specific customer.

6  Repeat for the remaining customers.

So, basically I need to automate the keystrokes that are currently performed manually, while in the website. Similar to running a macro in Excel. What tools are the best options to achieve this (ie. Batch script in Python), and why? I'm open to all ideas. Thanks!

I do not know the technologies required to do this. I am reaching out to this technical community to determine which tools could work, so I will know what type of programmers to hire.

Comment: Just chop it up into pieces.  There are several packages for reading Excel files, including xlwings or even pandas.  Then, you can use `requests-html` or `Selenium` to control a browser.

Comment: Perhaps you don’t even need to emulate a whole browser, if you can instead just imitate the necessary HTTP requests directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pandas to read exel use selenium to open and atoumate login to website and extract page source and use beautiful soap to extract data from the html tags of the pahge source i just can say how to read the exel because the login and extract data requied information about the website

```
# Install required libraries
pip install pandas
pip install selenium

# Specify the path to the Excel file
excel_file_path = 'path_to_your_excel_file.xlsx'

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)
print(df)

# Set up Selenium webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the website and perform login
driver.get("your_domain")

# Add code to automate login using Selenium 
# this will be your xpath or css class for the login button username or password entry ....
# inser your username and password in this filed with send keys method and click on login button with .click() method


# Extract page source
page_source = driver.page_source

# Close the Selenium webdriver
driver.quit()

# Install BeautifulSoup if not already installed
pip install bs4

# Extract data from HTML using BeautifulSoup
# Add code to extract data using BeautifulSoup
```

read this docs:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)